# T-SQL Procedure as a Telerik Kendo Grid datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a Kendo Grid (in ASP.NET MVC C# Application).  The Kendo Grid is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RunSummary>()
      .Name("CheckedPatients")                    
      .DataSource(datasource => datasource                
            .Ajax().PageSize(25)        
            .ServerOperation(false)                                        
            .Sort(sort => sort.Add("TimeOn").Descending())
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetRunSummaries", "PatientReport")))               

      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.UniqueId).Title(ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Home.HomeStrings.UniqueId)
                  .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  class='primaryBox' id='#= UniqueId #' value='#= UniqueId #'>#= UniqueId #</input>");                        
              columns.Bound(c => c.RunNo).Title(SharedStrings.Run);
              columns.Bound(c => c.Birthdate).Title(SharedStrings.Birthdate).Format("{0:g}").Filterable(true);

              columns.Bound(c => c.customAge).Title(SharedStrings.Age)
                     .Filterable(
                         filterable => filterable
                             .UI("AgeFilter")
                             .Extra(false)
                             .Operators(operators => operators
                                 .ForString(str => str.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to"))
                                 )

                   );

              columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOn).Title(PatientStrings.DateOn)
                  .Format("{0:g}")
                  .Filterable(true);
              columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOff).Title(PatientStrings.DateOff)
                  .Format("{0:g}")
                  .Filterable(true);
              columns.Bound(c => c.DischargedAlive).Title(PatientStrings.DischargedAlive).Filterable(true);                  columns.Bound(c => c.ShowSubmitted).Title(PatientStrings.Submitted).Filterable(true);
              columns.Bound(c => c.SupportTypeEnum).Title(PatientStrings.SupportType).Filterable(true);              }
      )
      .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] {10, 25, 50, 100}))
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable( )
      .Events( e => e.FilterMenuInit("FilterMenuFuncWithAge") ) // apply x [closing box] on pop up filter box
      )
```

When the user checked suitable Unique Ids (or all Unique Ids, using the option Checked All), there are the buttons that provide checked UniqueIds to the action in the Controller to generate PDF :

```
<a href="#" onclick="checkAll();">Check All</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#" onclick="uncheckAll();">Uncheck All</a>&nbsp;
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Patient" id="hrefCheckedPatients" href="#" onclick="getChecked();">Generate Report</a>&nbsp;
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Patient" id="hrefAllCheckedPatients" style="display:none;" href="#" onclick="getAllChecked();">Generate Report</a>&nbsp;
```

The javascript functions checkAll() and getAllChecked() are:

```
function checkAll() {
        $('#hrefCheckedPatients').hide();
        $('#hrefAllCheckedPatients').show();

        $('input').prop('checked', 'checked');

        checkedArray = [];

        var dataSource = $('#CheckedPatients').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
        var filters = dataSource.filter();
        var allData = dataSource.data();
        var query = new kendo.data.Query(allData);
        var data = query.filter(filters).data;

        var totalNumber = data.length;        

        for (var i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++) {
            var currentDataItem = data[i];            
            checkedArray.push(currentDataItem.get("UniqueId"));
        }


    }

    function getAllChecked() {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PatientReport/ExportToPDF",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { uniqueIds: checkedArray },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {                    
                    $('#myFrame').attr('src', '/PatientReport/DownloadFile' + '?fName=' + data.fName);                   

                } 

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {                
                $("#effect:visible").fadeOut();
                $('#checkedMsg').text('@ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Patient.PatientStrings.CheckedError').show();
                $('#hrefCheckedPatients').blur();
            }
        });
        }
```

In the Controller PatientReportController I have the method "GetRunSummaries":

```
 public JsonResult GetRunSummaries([ELSORegistry.Helpers.CustomDataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var center = Session["Center"] as Center;
        var centerId = center != null && center.CenterNo != 0 ? center.CenterId : (Guid?)null;

        List<RunSummary> myList = new Repository().GetRunSummariesWithIncompleteStoredProcedure(centerId);

        return Json(myList.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

(In Repository I call a stored procedure which returns fields for RunSummary). The code that calls the stored procedure is:

```
public List<RunSummary> GetRunSummariesWithIncompleteStoredProcedure(Guid? centerId = null)
        {

            List<RunSummary> runSummaries = new List<RunSummary>();
            var context = new ELSORegistryEntities();

            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            string connection = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IGD_spPatientListReportFillGrid", con);

                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter @CenterId = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@CenterId"
                    ,
                    DbType = DbType.Guid
                    ,
                    Value = centerId.HasValue ? (object)centerId : DBNull.Value
                };

                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(@CenterId);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    RunSummary runSummary = new RunSummary();

                    runSummary.UniqueId = rdr["UniqueId"].ToString();
                    runSummary.RunNo = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["RunNo"]);
                    runSummary.Birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["Birthdate"]);
                    runSummary.customAge = rdr["customAge"].ToString();
                    runSummary.TimeOn = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["TimeOn"]);

                    if (rdr["TimeOff"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        runSummary.TimeOff =Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["TimeOff"]);
                    }

                    if (rdr["DischargedAlive"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        runSummary.DischargedAlive = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["DischargedAlive"]);
                    }

                    if (rdr["ShowSubmitted"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        runSummary.ShowSubmitted = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["ShowSubmitted"]);
                    }


                    runSummaries.Add(runSummary);

                }
            }

            return runSummaries;

        }
```

My problem is that the code works very slowly, and the client has to wait for too long to see the Kendo Grid. Is it possible to send the List to the Kendo Grid without reading each line in the Reader? How can I speed up the code?

Comment: alenan, I realize this is old (posted in 2016), but it is what I need to do now. Did you ever find out what was wrong with your code above? I want to study what you did, but I would rather avoid bad code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Use Kendo DatasourceRequest in return instead to returning List object.

Also send only required records (equal to page size) of the Kendo gird in the row.

Make .ServerOperation(true) send only the necessary record from Controller when user move to next page/sorting/filtering grids.You can pass a parameter to the SQL stored procedure called pagesize and page to get required records.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
var employees = db.Employees.Where(e => e.IsActive);
var employeeViewModel = employees.Project().To<EmployeeViewModel>();
var results = employeeViewModel.ToDataSourceResult(request);
return Json(results);
}
```

**Edit:**

Please check whether the below logic works:

Scenario 1: Generate PDF for all Unique IDs

I think it is easy since you need all the Unique ID not necessary it should come from Grid, You can get this using a modified version of the Action of "GetRunSummaries" and the value from Session["Center"].

Scenario 2: Generate PDF for the selected Unique IDs

When user Click (check/uncheck) a particular row in the grid populate a global array like. It may be slightly difficult than the below code, but you can do it.

```
$(".primaryBox").on('click', '#CheckedPatients', function()
{
//Fill a global/public array named "checkedArray = [];" with the Unique Id value of that particular Checkbox whenever user check that respective checkbox
});
```

And on click of "Generate" button

```
$("#hrefCheckedPatients").on('click', function(){
// get value from global array checkedArray[];
// call the Ajax function and send the value from above array.
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and help. I have updated my method "GetRunSummaries" in the Controller according to your advice.When I put .ServerOperation(true) everything works very fast, but I have a checked column (UniqueId) in the Kendo Grid and when .ServerOperation on true, The Kendo Grid doesn't send all checked items to the Controller, so I have to use .ServerOperation(false).

Comment: Do you mean checkbox column as Unique ID? How it's possible? Please explain further.

Comment: Here you are. I just have updated my code. The column UniqueId in the grid has a template with checkbox, and the users can check some of UniqueIds or all UniqueIds. The checked UniqueIds via Ajax go to the Action in the Controller to generate PDF based on checked UniqueIds. When ServerOperation(true) then Kendo Grid doesn't allow to select all Unique Ids (sends only the first page with 25 UniqueIds). If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is useful.